# stopping the repetition of decimal separator in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have built a compound interest calculator app. App is running almost and now I want to prevent the repetition of the . in the text field.

I have done following three things, but it is not preventing a user from typing more than 1 decimal separator:

1. conform the class to UITextFieldDelegate
2. connected the delegate property of the text fields to the view controller
3. added following functions for principal, interest, freq, years text fields:

   ```
   func principal(principal: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

       let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = principal.text?.rangeOfString(".")
       let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.rangeOfString(".")

       if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
           return false
       }
       else {
           return true
       }
   }

   func interest(interest: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

       let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = interest.text?.rangeOfString(".")
       let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.rangeOfString(".")

       if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
           return false
       }
       else {
           return true
       }
   }

   func freq(freq: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

       let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = freq.text?.rangeOfString(".")
       let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.rangeOfString(".")

       if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
           return false
       }
       else {
           return true
       }
   }

   func years(years: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

       let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = years.text?.rangeOfString(".")
       let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.rangeOfString(".")

       if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
           return false
       }
       else {
           return true
       }
   }
   ```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  func principal(principal: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
```

is not how you conform to the protocol.

You have to match the full signature exactly (names matter):

```
  func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

You need to use one and check the `textField` parameter against the text fields in your VC to see which one changed (if you have different behavior).

Since it looks like the four functions you have above are identical, you could just make sure you always refer to the parameter and not to the specific textfield in your implementation.

Comment: thanks it worked wonderfully for all textfields.. I removed all specific textfield implementation and used only one function with full signature exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't going to work:

```
if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil{}
```

According to Apple's docs, this method returns an NSRange structure giving the location and length in the receiver of the first occurrence of aString. Returns {NSNotFound, 0} if aString is not found or is empty (@"").

So instead of checking for nil you need to check for a non existent range

```
if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != NSNotFound && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != NSNotFound{}
```